# C/C++ Build Settings in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I admit this is the first time I am using Eclipse for C/C++. I thought I would get a similar dialog like this by going project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings.

[image]

But I get this.

[image]

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Click [C/C++ Build] and then check if "Generate Makefiles Automatically" is selected or not under the Builder Setting tab.

Comment: I see the second dialog when I create a new Makefile project (the other project types give me the first type of dialog). Following Jesse Good's advice changed it to the first type for me.

Comment: @JesseGood Unfortunately, the checkbox is disabled.

Comment: Is it checked or not checked?

Comment: @JesseGood I made an answer from your comment before seeing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: This was caused by having multiple set of C++ compilers in system paths. By resolving the system path, I solved the problem above. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you create a project using **File** > **New** > **Makefile Project with Existing Code**.

To resolve it, right-click on the project, select **Properties**, navigate to **C/C++ Build**, and check **Generate Makefiles automatically**

[image]